# Moving data from one GameCenter account to another

Tags: ipad, applications

I have a GameCenter account on my iPad that is used by the entire family (each member has their own iPad). I play Clash of Clans and would like to move the Clash of Clans saved data form the family GameCenter account to a new one GameCenter account that I will set up. How can I do that so I don't lose all my progress with this game?

Answer (score -1):

You can logout from Settings -> Game Center then log in with another Apple ID.

Comment: Why this down vote? Question is about Game Center or game progress? Game progresses are independent from Game Center and, logging out from Game Center, you don't lose your game progresses...